# Add all with lists?

Tags: apex

Does the addall method for lists always add the paramater to the end of the calling list? That is, does this list always produce {1,2,3,4,5,6}? I ran it in my sandbox, and it appears that way?

```
List <Integer> x = new List <Integer> {1,2,3};
List <Integer> y = new List <Integer> {4,5,6};
x.addall(y);
system.debug(x);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `addAll` always **appends** the list in the argument to the original list. Lists are collections of indexed elements, therefore the index (position) of the elements in the list is preserved.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When you add all values from one list to another list, it increases the indexes of the receiving list and populates them with the values from the origin list.

Just like you are seeing in your test. Also, it adds them in the order they are in the origin list.